# move body to specific point in world coordinates at a constant speed

Tags: libgdx

I have a kinematic body with gravity 0  which I want to move from a specific point to a specific point in my world coordinates. I've  tried to adjust the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516945/calculate-correct-impluse-or-force-to-move-a-box2d-body-to-a-specific-position/24519641)
to the one below. But the body stays still and doesn't move?

```
  @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);

    //Target position in world coordinates
    Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(4.5142856f, -4.228572f);

    //target speed
    float targetSpeed = 1f;

    //direction
    Vector2 direction = targetPosition.sub(body.getPosition());

    //distance
    float distanceToTravel = direction.nor().len2();

    // For most of the movement, the target speed is ok
    float speedToUse = targetSpeed;

    float distancePerTimestep = speedToUse / 60.0f;
    if ( distancePerTimestep > distanceToTravel )
        speedToUse *= ( distanceToTravel / distancePerTimestep );

    Vector2 desiredVelocity = direction.scl(speedToUse);
    Vector2 changeInVelocity = desiredVelocity.sub(body.getLinearVelocity());

    Vector2 force = new Vector2(changeInVelocity.scl(body.getMass() * 60.0f));
    System.out.println(force);

    body.applyForce(force, body.getWorldCenter(), true);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The method below will return the correct velocity so that the body can reach the target point.

```
public Vector2 calculateVelocity(Vector2 target) {
    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(target.x - body.getPosition().x, target.y - body.getPosition().y ).nor();
    float speed = Constants.enemySpeed;
    return new Vector2( speed * direction.x, speed * direction.y );
}
```